# Show $P(X|Z_1,...,Z_n,Y)\not = P(X|Z_1,...,Z_n) \Leftrightarrow P(Y|Z_1,...,Z_n,X)\not = P(Y|Z_1,...Z_n)$

Tags: probability, random-variables

If we have two random variables $X,Y$ and a set of random variables $\{Z_1,...,Z_n\}$, are there any common proofs of the result in the title? Which theorems does this follow after?

Answer (score 3):

The starting point here is the definition of conditional probability:
$$
P(X|Y) = {P(X,Y) \over P(Y)}
$$
Then just repeatedly applying that gets the result.

Just to make it easier to view, write $Z\equiv Z_1, Z_2, ..., Z_n$. Then
$$
P(X|Z,Y)={P(X,Y,Z)\over P(Y,Z)}={P(Y|Z,X)\times P(Z,X) \over P(Y|Z)\times P(Z)} = {P(Y|Z,X)\times P(X|Z) \over P(Y|Z)} 
$$
Thus
$$
{P(X|Z,Y)\over P(X|Z)}= {P(Y|Z,X) \over P(Y|Z)}
$$

Comment: How does this suggest that when $P(X|Z,Y)\not = P(X|Z)$ then $P(Y|Z,X)\not = P(Y|Z)$, and vice-versa?

Comment: @Parker - maybe you can try to do just a little work here. All you need to do is to rearrange the equation.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Parker - if you are happy with the solution, you can mark it as accepted using the tick mark on the left of the text.

Comment: Can you show me how you got each part of the equality? Is there a wikipedia reference I can look at?

Comment: Like how do we get [P(Y|Z,X)P(Z,X)]/[P(Y|Z)P(Z)] from P(X,Y,Z)/P(Y,Z)?

Comment: @Parker - everything in the equation follows from the definition of conditional probability.

Comment: Can you please explain just that step, though. I still don't quite understand how to derive it.

Comment: The P(X,Y,Z)/P(Y,Z) = step is confusing me.

Comment: P(X,Y,Z)=P(Y,Z,X) and P(Y,Z,X)/P(Z,X)=P(Y|Z,X). If you can't do it from that, you need to go back to basic algebra.

Comment: So where do the addition P(Z,X) in the numerator and P(Z) in the denominator come from?

Comment: Sorry, this is the only part that is confusing me.

Comment: @Parker - if you cannot rearrange these equations, you need to go back and study basic algebra. Can you please stop asking me about it because I cannot solve your problems.

Comment: I'm honestly trying to understand what you're talking about. If we have P(X,Y,Z)/P(Y,Z), then this equals P(X|Y,Z). So how are you getting P(Y|Z,X)P(Z,X)/P(Y|Z)P(Z) from P(X,Y,Z)/P(Y,Z)?

Comment: @Parker - please stop posting comments under this answer.

Comment: No longer an answer. Thank you.

Comment: @Parker if you continue to post under this answer I will delete the answer and ask the moderators to deal with you.

Comment: Please delete it. It's worthless to me.

Comment: @Parker: do you realize that $P(X,Y,Z)=P(Y,Z,X)$? I'm mentioning this because you keep conditioning on $Y,Z$ whereas you should be conditioning on $Z,X$.

Comment: @Alex R. I explicitly wrote "P(X,Y,Z)=P(Y,Z,X) and P(Y,Z,X)/P(Z,X)=P(Y|Z,X)" above. I also added a definition of conditional probability in response to Parker's query. Parker's difficulty here surely is more than it's possible for anyone to reasonably answer.